# Ice Stone (Pokemon Sword)

Tags: pokemon-sword-shield

I'm new and I was wondering what type of Pokemon take Ice Stones in Pokemon Sword? I have tried to give the stone to my Ice Pokemon and it says "Incompatible," if anyone knows the answer to this question please respond back. Thank You!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Pokémon Sword & Shield, there are only 4 Pokémon that evolve using an [Ice Stone](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Ice_Stone):

- Alolan Sandshrew -> Alolan Sandslash
- Alolan Vulpix -> Alolan Ninetales
- Galarian Darumaka -> Galarian Darmanitan
- Eevee -> Glaceon

Comment: Thank You very much!